# why columns of csv file are shifting one cell to the right after downloading?

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have a csv file, on which i am running a R script.While previewing the file in google mail, the first cell is having value ";User". After getting downloaded, the the first cell is empty and the ";User " along with other column names is shifting by one cell to right.
Does anybody have a clue , as why it may happen?

Comment: I'd guess that the leading `;` is being interpreted as a column separator. Removing it should solve your problem.

Comment: can you give a reproducible example and the code you are using to import it?

Comment: If removing the leading ";" does not work provide the result of `readLines("filename", 3)`. What happens to the last column name? If there is one less column name than columns, R assumes the first column is a row name and does not label it.

Comment: Thanks everybody. jdobres answer helped :)